# Dictionary is not supported for deserialization of an array

Tags: jquery, .net, vb.net, json, .net-3.5

**UPDATED:**

I have the following code, where I am trying to use `returned` JSON data, deserialize it, and return 1 part of that data back to the user.

```
<%@ Page Language="VB" Debug="True" EnableViewState="false" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="System.Web.Script.Serialization" %>

<script runat="server">
    Class Item
        Public Property some_number() As Double
            Get
                Return m_some_number
            End Get
            Set(ByVal value As Double)
                m_some_number = value
            End Set
        End Property
        Private m_some_number As Double
        Public Property some_text() As String
            Get
                Return m_some_text
            End Get
            Set(ByVal value As String)
                m_some_text = value
            End Set
        End Property
        Private m_some_text As String
        Public Property serial_number() As String
            Get
                Return m_serial_number
            End Get
            Set(ByVal value As String)
                m_serial_number = value
            End Set
        End Property
        Private m_serial_number As String
    End Class


    Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
        Response.Clear()
        Response.Write(set_profiles())
        Response.End()
    End Sub

    Function set_profiles() As String
        ' get returned json data
        Dim strChanged As String = CType(Request.Form("strChanged"), String)

        ' deserialize returned data
        Dim jss = New JavaScriptSerializer()

        ' assuming i need to change this line now?
        Dim dict As Dictionary = jss.Deserialize(List(Of Item))(strChanged)

        Return dict("some_number")
    End Function
</script>
```

I don't understand how to deserialize into the `Item` class, then how to get the data back out.

Comment: jsonText is the the data I have posted above, the data which has the square brackets.

Comment: I meant: Which type is it? How is it filled with data?

Comment: I am sending the data back to the server via ajax (jquery) in the form of json `changed.push({some_number:id, date_time:$('input#' + mydate).val(), serial_number:the_serial});`, then I am stringigying it like this on clientside `$.ajax({
                    url: 'set_profile.aspx?rand=' + Math.random(),
                    type: 'POST',
                    dataType: 'json',
                    data: { strChanged: JSON.stringify( changed ) },`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your data is an array, and you're trying to deserialize it into Dictionary. This won't work.

Either change your input data or deserialize it to an array.

You can also declare a class and use it in the deserialization.

C#, sorry:

```
class Item
{
    public double some_number { get; set; }
    public string some_text { get; set; }
    public string serial_number { get; set; }
}
```

and deserialize to `List(Of Item)`

Comment: How do I deserialize to an array?

Comment: `jss.Deserialize(Of Item())(jsonText)` or however you do `Item[]` in VB

Comment: I have created the Item class in VB.NET, please see update 1 in original question.  I am not sure how to do the next part, i.e. `and deserialize to List(Of Item)`

Comment: Replace `jss.Deserialize(Of Dictionary(Of String, String))(jsonText)` with `jss.Deserialize(Of List(Of Item))(jsonText)`

Comment: I have tried that, i.e. `Dim dict = jss.Deserialize(Of List(Of Item))(strChanged)`, `but Return dict("some_number")` gives an error.  I'm probably not storing to the right variable?  I've also tried `Dim dict As Item = jss.Deserialize(Of List(Of Item))(strChanged)` but get, `generic list cannot be converted to Item`