# JSON string to dictionary object error

Tags: c#

I have the below code in my C# program where I need to convert a json structure to a dictionary.

```
string json = @"[{""id"":""51851"",""name"":""test {""id"":""527"",""name"":""test1""}]"; 
    var json_serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
    Dictionary<string, object> dictionary = json_serializer.Deserialize<Dictionary<string, object>>(json);
```

while running this, I am getting the below error.

```
Type 'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[[System.String, mscorlib, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089],[System.Object, mscorlib, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]]' is not supported for deserialization of an array.
```

Can anyone help me to figure out what wrong in this?

Comment: Would this not return an array of objects instead of a dictionary?

Comment: Please don't put tag information in your title. The tagging system here is very good at classifying things, and doesn't need help. :-) Please see [Should questions include "tags" in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/19190/172661). Thanks.

Comment: Matthew is correct.  You are trying to deserialize an array into a dictionary.  See this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6692821/dictionary-is-not-supported-for-deserialization-of-an-array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This: `"[{""id"":""518523721""}]"` is an array of objects.

Remove the square braces so that you are left with:

```
"{""id"":""518523721""}"
```

This should then de-serialize to `Dictionary<string, object>`.

**EDIT** (based on comment below)

For multiple **objects**, the JSON is incorrect.  the following JSON structure should de-serialize as you require:

```
"{
    "51851" : { "id" : "51851", "name" : "test" },
    "527" : { "id" : "527", "name" : "test" }
}"
```

Comment: for a single element this will work. what about if  string json = @"{""id"":""51851"",""name"":""test {""id"":""527"",""name"":""test1""}";

Comment: Hi, that's still possible, your JSON will need to be changed though, see my edit.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. Instead of `object` use `dynamic` for integer.

```
Dictionary<string, dynamic> dictionary = json_serializer.Deserialize<Dictionary<string, dynamic>>(json)
```

Also as Oliver mentioned, remove the square brackets. It is used for arrays.

Comment: im using .net 3.5 where dynamic not supported.

Comment: @user1357872 Oh right. Just remove the square brackets. Let us know if that works.

Comment: no Jay Patel. I'm getting Invalid JSON primitive error if remove the square brackets.

Comment: Check Oliver's answer. I thought the error was due to `int` as `object` not being serialized. The JSON structure might be incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

Your JSON represents an array of objects, not a dictionary.

If your JSON is incorrect (you didn't intend on an array) you can remove the square brackets and your code should work.

Otherwise, you change the code to what you're deserializing.

```
var dictionaries = json_serializer.Deserialize<List<Dictionary<string, object>>>(json);

foreach (var dictionary in dictionaries)
{
    Console.WriteLine(dictionary["id"]); // 518523721
}
```